# Laravel form model binding not populating file (photo) field

Tags: html, forms, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

Im using laravel 5.3 and im using same form for create and edit.

the form contains file field

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Photo: </label>
        {!! Form::input('file', 'photo', null, array('class'=>'form-control TabOnEnter', 'tabindex' => 6)) !!}
    </div>
```

This photo field work good while creating, but in editing the field goes empty., that is while editing other fields are populated from db, but this photo field is populating. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you dont hold images in your database, just links.

The input field is of type `file`, which accepts a file, not a string. 
You should instead display maybe an `<img src="">` with the photo link to hint the user.

Comment: im using same code for create and edit, if user not selected anything then it will go empty